Jetbrains Rider: Prevent Indentation in file-scoped namespace
I am trying to make Rider not indent my c# code that is within a file-scoped namespace, because currently what Rider does, both when creating a new class and when reformatting existing code is the following:
namespace PreviewNamespace ;

    public class C
    {
    }

and i would want (also notice the whitespace between the namespace and the semicolon)
namespace PreviewNamespace;

public class C
{
}

What i tried so far:

Well i wished, i was able to edit the before/after preview that rider shows under Editor>Code Style> C#> Syntax Style>Code Body>Namespaces but unfortunately it's readonly.

It wouldn't really make sense, that this toggles it, but i also tried unchecking "Indent inside namespace declaration" under ...>C#>braces layout


Maybe it's just me and i need a clean installation of Rider or i'm just blind and completely missed a setting for this.
Either way, any help is greatly appreciated!
Cheers

Can you try to create a GitHub repo with a repro case so that I can play around with it? So far, I was unable to reproduce your issue - it always works for me ‍♂️

@mu88 Thanks for reaching out! Before i create a github repo (which i'll happily make if this doesn't work), i want to test two things.

For me the following already fails: Create empty console application, then replace the default Hello World print simply with "public class Testing {}", then Rider shows me the hint/warning to move to correct namespace, apply the fix and then rider malformats it. Same for you?
in the setting here (Editor>Code Style> C#> Syntax Style>Code Body>Namespaces) is the "after" (right side) also malformatted for you?
Thanks again!


No and no - both are formatted "correctly", i.e. matching your expectation of not being indented

@mu88 Thanks again for your comments, compared with a clean installation of rider and found the issue, as usual after searching through every other code style c# setting first :P. See the answer i posted should i be of interest.

I managed to figure out what caused this issue for me with a side-by-side setting comparison thanks to mu88's comments:
Under Editor>Code Style> C#> Other I had the box Revert to old formatting engine (Resharper Other-section) ticked, unticking it resolved the issue.
I hope this helps anyone that also has the same issue.
EDIT: I also just noticed, that when Revert to old formatting engine is ticked, the checkbox Braces Layout > Indent inside namespace declaration (for me at least) changes nothing in the preview below.
